# How to render actors in stage with the box2d physics applied to them?

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I have been making games in Libgdx and the only way that is use to make the game is through scene2d Stage. I make a BaseActor which extends Actor and make my actors and characters from BaseActor class.

But the thing is I wanted to make better games and use physics in it. I searched and searched finally I found box2d. I made a game in it using my own way again BaseActor, BaseBody,and Stage.

BaseBody for making bodies, BaseActor for making actors for stage and probably the same as my old ones but when playing it the gravity that I used can't move the objects faster. the movement is so slow. Then I again searched and searched and find that the problems is with metric system. I was using pixels and that made my game very bad. There was something I found on the internet with the name of ppm. I really don't have any idea how to use it or what it really is or any other thing related to it.

Then I tried to find a scene editor and found overlap2d and visEditor both goes down and not supported any more. And I want to say that I don't know the meaning of camera.combined, camera.setToOrtho and matrix. And finally when I made a game in box2d at least better than my old broken projects but still can't use metric system and a lot of bugs I saw that when the box with the image goes to the edges of the ground the body gets some kind of rotation but the image still is the same and I even use body.getangle and set image's rotation with that it still doesn't rotates. And I don't know how I should make things work again.

[image]

This is the game that I made using visEditor and works fine except setSize of the images and many more bugs about the origin x and y. I used scene loader of the viseditor in this and no Stage. And this use metric system.

[image]

And this is my game that I used stage and other things but no scene editor.

[image]

--- what is the meaning of matrix , camera.setToOrtho , camera.combined.

--- how to use metric system instead of pixels in both box2d and Stage.

--- is there any good, supported, and updated scene editor for libgdx.

--- is there any other way to make game instead of stage and actors but with classes and more efficient and code reusable for libgdx and box2d

--- how to apply the physics of the body in the image too.

--- am I coding right with using stage and actors and filling the body with image using the batch.draw() and using the body position and more or is there any method that fills body with image or any other at least better than my way.

Comment: Camera.SetToOrtho :  Sets this camera to an orthographic projection, centered at (viewportWidth/2, viewportHeight/2), with the y-axis pointing up
  * or down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found some answers for some of your questions.

> what is the meaning of matrix , camera.setToOrtho , camera.combined.

ans: I don't know either sorry.

> how to use metric system instead of pixels in both box2d and Stage.

ans: you can do such thing by dividing every object's width and height and the camera with a constant PIXEL2METER.

(first make a Constant static value name it PIXEL2METER then in your baseActor class if you are loading texture through it just setSize with the width and height of the texture divided by PIXEL2METER and then make two variables your desire width and height and divide them by PIXEL2METER and make a Orthographic camera and call the method setToOrtho(false, width,height) the set this camera to your Stage by getting getViewport().setCamera(camera) or setting a viewport with the camera)

> is there any good , supported , and updated scene editor for libgdx.

ans: actually No . there isn't any overlap2d and visEditor are the one i know too but they both deprecated and are not supported anymore with many bugs. libgdx is only a game framework so it doesn't have it's own scene editor.

> is there any other way to make game instead of stage and actors but with classes and more efficient and code reusable for libgdx and box2d

ans: actually programming language is a very wide and deep knowledge you can make a game with many ways but the thing is the greatest way to make game is the way you can the way you know and trust me you are gonna find solutions for your problems.

> how to apply the physics of the body in the image too.

ans: I don't know sorry.

> am I coding right with using stage and actors and filling the body with image using the batch.draw() and using the body position and more or is there any method that fills body with image or any other at least better than my way.

ans: again the greatest way is the way you know and I haven't heard of any method that fill body with a texture or such thing but keep searching anyway and don't start coding unless you haven't found any answers. If there weren't any ways just create one.